# DSP Concepts Visually Explained

Tags: discussion

One of my all-time favorite SE questions is [Visually stunning math concepts which are easy to explain](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/733754/visually-stunning-math-concepts-which-are-easy-to-explain).

Has there been any similar post on DSP.SE? Would this be an appropriate thing to post?

Comment: Go for it! The worst that can happen, the question can be locked. I won't close it though ;)

Comment: Great, I'll post it once my 40 min cooldown runs out.

Comment: I like it. We've had a few cool illustrations like that posted over the years, but it would be nice to have something all in one place. It should be community wiki, of course.

Comment: Should I do anything to make it a community wiki, or is that a situation where high rep users vote on it?

Comment: Posted https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/51573/dsp-concepts-visually-explained

Comment: I went ahead and converted it to wiki. It's just an SE convention for "list of X" type questions (because they're not about solving a particular problem, but still add value).

Comment: Sounds good to me! So I think the mods are unanimous. :-)

Answer (score 3):

As `datageist` and `jojek` say, I think this is an appropriate question to post, but we should make the whole thing community wiki as `datageist` says:

> It's just an SE convention for "list of X" type questions (because they're not about solving a particular problem, but still add value).